# Converting Notes to CC Values in Digital Performer

Tags: midi, editing

I am fairly new to Digital Performer and have been given a midi stream and an Audio Unit (AU) instrument. Unfortunately, the midi stream was made when the instrument used notes as control codes to change from one mode (say, staccato) to another but now uses control/CC values. Is there a way in DP to convert note down to a control code event such like converting CC alone does now?

I see I can select `Region->Reassign Continuous Data` to map a CC value to a CC value but what I would like is to convert Note Down to CC32 Value 5 in the controllers. However, you cannot take a note and convert it to a CC value in this menu. Is this possible and if not is it possible to create a plugin or filter to accomplish the same thing?

[image: Example CC Conversion]